# Get elements inside applied cutplanes autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Forge's viewer.setCutPlanes() function to set the cutplanes along with levels, so it will apply the cutplanes horizontally to cut the model level wise. I have two Vector4, as planes, I pass these two planes to the setCutPlanes() function. Now I want to get all elements those are inside the cutplanes, which means, only those elements which are visible in viewer after applying the cutplanes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Viewer APIs to iterate through the geometry fragments of all objects in your design, get their bounding boxes, and check whether they're between your clipping planes. The process of obtaining the geometry bounds is explained in this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer.

Comment: I can get bounding box for all elements in the model, but how can I check whether they are inside my two planes? my planes look like - THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 1, 10) and THREE.Vector4(0, 0, -1, 10). Can you share some example?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any examples for this. Looking at the shader code, points in the world coordinate system are culled by a cutplane using a simple dot product, e.g., `shouldBeClipped = dot(vec4(worldPosition, 1.0), cutplane) > 0`, so the 4 values of each cutplane should really just be an X, Y, Z of a normal, and a distance from origin in the world coordinate system.

Comment: So a simple approach in your case might be to take the 8 vertices of each bounding box, run the dot-product test on them, and if all 8 tests are negative, it would mean that all 8 corners of the bounding box are within the cutplanes, and the object could therefore be considered as being "inside".

Answer (score 0):

You can also re-use the 'window selection' example (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-part-iii) and switch the 8 frustum points to the section plane points.